# When using someone else's application code do I need to run Cmake to get the project structure for my operating system.

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, cmake, makefile

I am getting into a position where I have to use other people code for projects, for example [openTLD](http://www.gnebehay.com/tld/). I want to change some of the code to give it more functionality and use it in a diffrent way. What I have found is that many people have packaged their files in such a way that you are supposed to use

> cmake

and then

> make

and sometimes after that

> make install

I don't want to install the software on my system. What I am looking to do is get these peoples code to a point where I can add to it in Eclipse or even just using Nano and then compile it.

At what point is the code in a workable/usable state. Can I use it after doing cmake or do I need to also call make? Is my thinking correct that it would be better to edit the code after calling cmake as opposed to before? I am not going to want my finished code to be cross platform supported, it will only be on Linux. Is it easer to learn cmake and edit the code befor running cmake as opposed to not learning cmake and using the code afterwards, if that is possible?

Comment: None of those commands is necessary for you to edit the code. Those are all build related commands.

Comment: Usually `make install` doesn't actually install the program on your system, it rather copies in a folder that you select all binaries generated and the headers containing the interface to access them. This collection might also be moved on another machine, with compatible operating  system. If you need to build a project, you first configure and generate the makefiles with CMake, and then actually call make. Actually, you can also generate an Eclipse project if you select the right generator at cmake first run. You don't need to know a lot about CMake, unless you modify the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little open ended.

Looking at the opentld project, there is a binary and a library available for use. If you are interested in using the binary in your code, you need to download the executables(Linux executables are not posted). If you are planning to use the library, you have two options. Either you use the pre-built library or build it during your build process. You would include the header files in your custom application and link with the library.

If you add more details, probably others can pitch in with new answers or refine the older ones.